# Can't seek on HTML5 video

Tags: html, node.js, video, webm, http-content-range

When I serve a webm video from my server, I can't seem to be able to seek it on Chrome. I've looked around and it seems it has something to do with the content-range, but the information online is extremely unclear. I'm currently running a node server... how do I go about setting up partial content ranges while serving webm video?

Comment: without showing the HTML and JS you use to present your video to the user, your question is unfortunately also unclear. Even if you think you're using "the standard HTML for that", we have no idea what you're thinking of, so please show us the HTML/JS code you're using. If this is already live, a jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net demonstrator would be very useful as additional link for us to look at.

Comment: What kind of webserver software do you use?

Comment: I had a different issue - are you able to seek in VLC? this will solve that if you can't: https://superuser.com/questions/489015/seek-issues-in-webm-vp8-ivf-ogg-file